# Angular typeahead, filtering, $resource and promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, ngresource

I'm implementing a typeahead using angular like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="bindingValue" 
    typeahead="item for item in items($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue" 
    typeahead-wait-ms="{{autocompletionDelay}}"> </input>
```

In my controller, I use $resource to retrieve an array of strings from an ajax service.  In order to deal with the asynchronous nature of the request, I use $q and promises.

```
$scope.items = function (value) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    var results = $scope.resource.getResults( {text:value }, function() {
        d.resolve(results);
    }); 
    return d.promise;
}
```

The result is correct, except the client-side filtering is not happening.  Every input into my textbox results in the entire array returned from the service being displayed in the typeahead popup.

What am I doing wrong?  Am I allowed to use the filter like that in html when I populate my array server-side?

Comment: I'm a little confused, if you're returning a presumably narrower and narrower list, why use filter at all? Isn't the list being filter by that action?

Comment: One thing to note is you shouldn't need the `filter:$viewValue` if your async request is filtering them server side.

Comment: I would like to filter client-side as well as in my service.  I'd like both options.  Is this behavior supported?